# Assets (pixel & tonic) channel form - show images only by author

Tags: assets

I'm using Assets to provide a form for members to post an icon.  I'm using the "{field:assets_field_name}" method to provide the file upload ability.

I love it and it works great, however I want users to only see files that they have uploaded and not the whole S3 bucket contents (everyone elses icon uploads as well as theirs).

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Also - is there a way to when they post a new icon to attach meta data to the upload like the author?

Comment: This is actually another question. Please post it separately as its own question.

Comment: I've found a solution to do what I needed here:

http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/4866/restrict-assets-directory-access-per-user-in-safecracker

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe Assets has support for this (they didn't when I checked recently). It should be doable with [Channel Images](http://www.devdemon.com/channel_images), and, very possibly, [Photo Frame](https://objectivehtml.com/photo-frame).

Comment: Thanks Nick, I'm now wondering if there is a way to use the assets ability to create sub-folders so that when someone signs up, create an extension that will use the assets hook to create new folder with the users ID... but then how to call the folder from the channel form?  Ugh..

Comment: Might be possible, I guess; given that there's already an existing and well-supported add-on that can handle it, I'd just go with one of those for managing the files in question.